# MySQL character set was overrides by someone. How is it possible and how to deal with it?

Tags: mysql, utf-8, server, character-encoding, mariadb

Using a web server, originally I set character sets for my website ,with mysql commands[ALTER DATABASE dbname CHARACTER SET charset COLLATE somecollation],and the results was like this:

```
| character_set_client     | utf8mb4                    |
| character_set_connection | utf8mb4                    |
| character_set_database   | utf8                       |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | utf8mb4                    |
| character_set_server     | utf8mb4                    |
| character_set_system     | utf8
```

But recently, I found that it was changed as following:

```
| character_set_client     | utf8                    |
| character_set_connection | utf8                    |
| character_set_database   | latin1                  |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                  |
| character_set_results    | utf8                    |
| character_set_server     | utf8                    |
| character_set_system     | latin1
```

And characters on my website is collapsed. After I noticed that issue, I again used mysql commands and fixed it, but websites still displayed collapsed characters.

So I suspect that

1. Administrator modified system setting for db, it's mariadb, or upgraded it that caused to reset charsets. Is it probable to cause this kind of issue when admin modify/upgrade/reset system?
2. The system setting may overrides the setting that I change with mysql commands.
   Could .cnf files or .conf files override existing db character setting, even if (even after) SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set%';
   SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'collation%'; shows desired character setting? The server is a shared server, and I don't have permission as admin on the server.

What do you think?

And I also want to know:

```
3. Is it possible to make strict and robust database character sets against admin's system setting?
```

Thanks

Comment: 1) this is anyone's guess. 2) Yes 3) the best thing is to set these when you connect to mysql.

Comment: Shadow@ set these when you connect to mysql:That's what I did for this issue. But I doubt it's the only way to solve this issue because it looks not a smart and clean way for me, or does it?

Comment: Move to a dedicated server with a dedicated mysql/mariadb instance and you can be smart about any of the settings. While you are on a shared host, you have to set your db settings on a session level.

Answer (score 0):

Several options:

- Set things appropriately in `my.cnf`
- Check that you don't have a personal `.my.cnf` that with `utf8`.
- Use `utf8mb4` in the connection string (which is very app-language dependent).
- Do this immediately after connecting:  `SET NAMES utf8mb4;`.